# Issue with FlatList in React Native displaying only 10 records

Tags: react-native, laravel-8

I'm experiencing an issue with FlatList in React Native where only 10 records are displayed, and I'm unable to load more items even when reaching the end of the list. I am using server-side pagination with a Laravel API.

```
I've verified that the API returns more than 10 records and that server-side pagination works correctly.
I've implemented client-side pagination logic to request the next page once the user reaches the bottom of the list.
I've tried adjusting onEndReachedThreshold and other props of FlatList.
```

Encountered Issue:
Despite my efforts, the list only loads 10 records and doesn't request more data when I reach the bottom. Here is the error (if any) I am receiving: [Include any specific error messages or details here]

Question:
How can I resolve this issue to load more items as the user scrolls to the bottom of the list? Are there specific configurations or practices I should follow for FlatList or server-side pagination with Laravel?

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {BASE_URL} from "../../constants/config";
import {getDataAmes} from "../../data/data_ames";
import {SIZES} from "../../constants/theme";
import Header from "../../components/Header";

const ListeAmesScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [ames, setAmes] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(null);
  const [isFetchingMore, setIsFetchingMore] = useState(false);
  const {datas} = getDataAmes();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    if (loading) return; // Évitez de charger plus de données si déjà en cours
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem("idprovider");

      const URL = `${BASE_URL}listeames?idprovider=${id}&page=${currentPage}`;

      const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Erreur de l'API: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const responseData = await response.json();

      if (currentPage === 1) {
        setAmes(responseData.data); // Pour la première page, définissez les données normalement
      } else {
        setAmes(prevAmes => [...prevAmes, ...responseData.data]); // Pour les pages suivantes, ajoutez les nouvelles données à la liste existante
      }
      setLastPage(responseData.last_page);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'appel de datas :",
        error,
      );
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
      setIsFetchingMore(false);
    }
  };

  const fetchMoreData = () => {
    if (currentPage < lastPage && !isFetchingMore) {
      setIsFetchingMore(true); // Indiquez que le chargement de la pagination a commencé
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [currentPage]);

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    //console.log("Item:", item);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handleItemPress(item)}
        onLongPress={() => handleLongPress(item)}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            padding: 10,
            alignItems: "center",
            //paddingVertical: 40,
            //borderBottomWidth: 1,
            //borderColor: "#00AEAD",
            width: SIZES.width,
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              borderRadius: 25,
              backgroundColor: "#00AEAD",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              marginRight: 10,
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{color: "white", fontSize: 22, fontWeight: "bold"}}>
              {item.nom.charAt(0)}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold"}}>
              {item.nom} {item.prenoms}
            </Text>
            <Text>Contact: {item.contact}</Text>
            <Text>
              Adresse: {item.pays} - {item.commune}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const handleLongPress = item => {
    // Ajoutez votre logique ici, par exemple afficher une alerte
    setTimeout(() => {
      Alert.alert(
        "Confirmation",
        "Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet élément ?",
        [
          {
            text: "Non",
            onPress: () => console.log("Annulé"),
            style: "cancel",
          },
          {
            text: "Oui",
            onPress: () => handleDelete(item),
          },
        ],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
    }, 1000); // Temps en millisecondes, ici 1000 millisecondes (1 seconde)
  };

  const handleDelete = async itemToDelete => {
    try {
      // Mettez à jour l'état isLoading si nécessaire
      //setIsLoading(true);
      //const {item} = route.params;

      const id = itemToDelete.id.toString();

      //console.log(id);
      const URL = `${BASE_URL}deleteame?id=${id}`;

      const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Erreur de l'API: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const responseData = await response.json();

      // Gérer la réponse de l'API si nécessaire
      console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData.data));

      // Handle the API response if necessary
      fetchData();
      // Peut-être naviguer vers une autre page après la suppression
      //navigation.navigate("PageApresSuppression");
    } catch (error) {
      // Gérer les erreurs de l'API
      console.error("Erreur de l'API :", error);

      //setIsLoading(false);

      // Afficher un message à l'utilisateur sur l'échec de la suppression
      alert("Échec de la suppression. Veuillez réessayer.");
    }
  };

  const handleItemPress = item => {
    // Naviguer vers l'écran de détails avec les informations de l'élément
    navigation.navigate("Ames", {item});
  };

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      style={{
        flexDirection: "column",
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "space-between",
      }}
      source={require("../../assets/images/mywaydesigns.png")}
      resizeMode="cover"
    >
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Header
          title="Mes Enregistrements"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("New")}
        />
      </View>

      <FlatList
        data={ames}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        onEndReached={fetchMoreData}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} // À ajuster selon le besoin
        ListFooterComponent={
          () => loading && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> // Vous pouvez personnaliser la couleur
        }
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default ListeAmesScreen;
```